# To get into the building I'll disguise as a reporter

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Choose the correct option:

> To get into the building I'll **disguise** as a reporter.
>   To get into the building I'll **disguise myself** as a reporter

**Disguise myself** is the correct sentence given.

But, if I use it other way and not use myself with it, will it be wrong grammatically?

Comment: Yes. Disguise needs to be acting on something. If you want to use a verb there without saying "myself," you could try "pose" or "pretend to be a reporter."

Comment: @AlexK http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/disguise , if I look at these sentences online, its not necessary that every time disguise needs to have a preposition with it. Please suggest.

Comment: @SeemaBhukar  - I'm not sure if you mean "preposition" or "object".   "Disguise" as a verb doesn't necessarily need a preposition, but it does need an object, because it is a transitive verb.

Comment: @SeemaBhukar In the examples in the link, you will notice that *disguise* is sometimes a noun and sometimes a verb.  When it's a verb, it always has an object, because it's a transitive verb.  When it doesn't have an object with it, it is because it is being used in the noun form.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that native speakers use the verb *disguise* transitively, that is, with a direct object. So one speaks of *disguising **oneself***.

This is true, it seems,   even though your sentence has two meanings:

> To get into the building I'll disguise myself as a reporter.

can mean

> To get into the building I'll put on the clothes of a reporter.

But it can also mean

> To get into the building I'll disguise myself as a reporter (does)

that is

> To get into the building I'll disguise myself using the same method as a reporter disguises himself

In other words, since reporters are not allowed in the building, reporters have to disguise themselves as something else in order to get in.

And since I'm a clergyman and clergymen are also not allowed in the building, I will disguise myself the same way as a reporter disguises himself.

Note this does not mean you have to disguise yourself as the same thing that the reporter disguises himself as. The reporter may disguise himself as a farmer, you might disguise yourself as a fireman.

A parallel usage of what I'm taking about is

> I'll play tennis as a tennis pro (does)

I will play tennis in the same way that a tennis pro plays tennis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be incorrect.  However, you could use *pose* in that situation.

> To get into the building, I'll pose as a reporter.

Also, both sentences should have a comma after 'building.'

Comment: @kittyconsultant good catch